# Summing row values after a groupby but based on a dictionary condition?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to figure out how to add row entries of  the numeric columns(supply,demand) . I am at a complete loss. My initial thoughts are to do this with a dictionary where i specify conditions within a dictionary(or perhaps there is another more efficient way to do this) ?. My second thought was to separate the data set such that each part has its own dataframe and then i use a bunch of conditionals but this would my last option since my dataset has about 10000 parts. In this example I only want to combine the supply and demand of rows with Planning location China and/or CH_China with plants US and/or China.
Dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Plant': ['China','New Zealand','US','US','Mexico'], 'Planning location': ['China','New Zealand','CH_China','US','China' ],'Part':[1,1,1,1,1],'Demand':[-5,6,7,8,9],'Supply':[4,10,-2,5,6]})
```

Expected result:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data={'Plant': ['New Zealand','China & US','US','Mexico'], 'Planning location': ['New Zealand','China & CH_China','US','China' ],'Part':[1,1,1,1],'Demand':[6,2,8,9],'Supply':[10,2,5,6]})
```

Comment: You only want to concatenate rows where `Plant` and `Location` values are either China or US?

Comment: Yes, only rows where Plant and Location values are either China or US for this example. I have several such combinations of Plant and location so I want to do it in a way that is efficient enough for 10000 unique parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to *group* US/China by Part number:

```py
plant_is_china_us = df["Plant"].isin(["China", "US"])
planning_is_china = df["Planning location"].isin(["China", "CH_China"])

df1 = (
    df[plant_is_china_us & planning_is_china]
    .groupby("Part", as_index=False)
    .sum()
)
df1[["Plant", "Planning location"]] = ["China & US", "China & CH_China"]

df2 = df[~(plant_is_china_us & planning_is_china)]
print(pd.concat([df2, df1]).reset_index(drop=True).to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Plant | Planning location | Part | Demand | Supply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | New Zealand | New Zealand | 1 | 6 | 10 |
| 1 | US | US | 1 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | Mexico | China | 1 | 9 | 6 |
| 3 | China & US | China & CH_China | 1 | 2 | 2 |